# Transfer not working on buy swaps with ERC20

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap, openzeppelin, ethereumj

I am trying to send a percentage of ethereum to my marketing wallet when someone buys or sells my token via uniswap. It seems to work on sells but not on buys... why is that? i get nothing transferred to my marketing wallet on buys. Is there something I am doing wrong? Any help on this will be appreciated

```
function sendETHToMarketing(uint256 amount) private {
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;
    
        swapTokensForEth(amount);
        uint256 newBalance = (address(this).balance).sub(initialBalance);
        marketingWallet.transfer(newBalance);
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");


        if(amount == 0) {
            super._transfer(from, to, 0);
            return;
        }
        

        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        
        bool canSwap = contractTokenBalance >= swapTokensAtAmount;

        if(
            canSwap &&
            !swapping &&
            !automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] &&
            from != liquidityWallet &&
            to != liquidityWallet
        ) {
            swapping = true;

            uint256 marketingTokens = contractTokenBalance.mul(marketingFee).div(totalFees);
            sendETHToMarketing(marketingTokens);

            uint256 swapTokens = contractTokenBalance.mul(liquidityFee).div(totalFees);
            swapAndLiquify(swapTokens);

            uint256 sellTokens = balanceOf(address(this));
            swapAndSendDividends(sellTokens);

            swapping = false;
        }


        bool takeFee = !swapping;

        // if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if(_isExcludedFromFees[from] || _isExcludedFromFees[to]) {
            takeFee = false;
        }
        
       

        if(takeFee) {
            uint256 fees = amount.mul(totalFees).div(100);

            if(automatedMarketMakerPairs[to]) {
                fees = fees.mul(1).div(100);
            }

            amount = amount.sub(fees);

            super._transfer(from, address(this), fees);
        }

        super._transfer(from, to, amount);

        try dividendTracker.setBalance(payable(from), balanceOf(from)) {} catch {}
        try dividendTracker.setBalance(payable(to), balanceOf(to)) {} catch {}

        if(!swapping) {
            uint256 gas = gasForProcessing;

            try dividendTracker.process(gas) returns (uint256 iterations, uint256 claims, uint256 lastProcessedIndex) {
                emit ProcessedDividendTracker(iterations, claims, lastProcessedIndex, true, gas, tx.origin);
            }
            catch {

            }
        }
    }

    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 tokens) private {
        // split the contract balance into halves
        uint256 half = tokens.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = tokens.div(2);

        // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
        // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
        // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
        // has been manually sent to the contract
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

        // swap tokens for ETH
        swapTokensForEth(half); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered

        // how much ETH did we just swap into?
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

        // add liquidity to uniswap
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
        
        emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {

        
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
        
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working" ? What is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the code correctly, but I suspect that for a "buy" the "from" is the UniswapPair.

```
if(
            canSwap &&
            !swapping &&
            !automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] && // <-- if from is UniswapPair, sendETHToMarketing is skipped 
            from != liquidityWallet &&
            to != liquidityWallet
   )
```